# A exercise on ismorphisms of rings of polynomials and complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to prove that $\,\,\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$  with $(x^2+1)=\{(x^2+1)f : f\in\mathbb{R}[x]\}$

Comment: Can you find a surjective homomorphism $\mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{C}$ whose kernel is $(x^2 + 1)$ ?

Comment: Joel I have not found the function  :(

Comment: Ok Jujian did not know about the points, my official language is Spanish. Thanks.

Comment: @Andres : You know such a function must map the polynomial $x^2+1$ to $0$ (because $x^2 + 1$ should be in the kernel), so what could the image of $x$ be ?

Comment: @Andres, What is your definition of $\mathbf{C}$?

Comment: Keenan $\mathbb{C}$ is the set of complex numbers

Comment: @Andres, I mean, what is your definition of the set of complex numbers? Is it the set of expressions $a+bi$ with $a,b\in\mathbf{R}$, a set of ordered pairs, or something else?

Comment: Keenan any of the two definitions

Comment: Joel I do not know the function to send $x^2+1$ to O  :(

Comment: @Andres What about $x\mapsto i$?

Comment: The function is $\varphi:\mathbb{R}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{C},\,\,\, \varphi(ax+b)=a+bi$??

Comment: @Andres: Not quite. You need the evaluation map $p(x) \mapsto p(i)$.

Comment: The function is $\varphi:\mathbb{R}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{C},\,\,\, \varphi(a_0 +a_1 x+a_2 x^2+a_3 x^3+...)=a_0+a_1 i$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\psi\colon \mathbb{R}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the map defined by $\psi(f(x)) = f(i)$.
Clearly $\psi$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-homomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras.
Suppose $\psi(f(x)) = 0$.
By the division formula, there exists $g(x), h(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that

$f(x) = (x^2 + 1)g(x) + h(x)$, where deg $h(x) < 2$.

Since $f(i) = 0$ and $i^2 + 1 = 0$, $h(i) = 0$.
Suppose $h(x) = ax + b$.
Then $ai + b = 0$.
Hence $a = b = 0$.
Hence $f(x) = (x^2 + 1)g(x)$.
Hence Ker $\psi = (x^2 + 1)$.
Therefore $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + 1) \cong \mathbb{C}$.